# After submission, page is not redirect(back) to main page in Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook

I've a facebook App where a form is pull from my website. After submit the form in facebook it's showing success message. But In my process.php page i set header code to re-direct to my main facebbok page after showing success message. But it's not rejecting. Do you know why ? and is there any solution ?

```
echo "<div class='success'><font color='green' size='5'>Congratulation!. Successfully submited your 
recipe. Thank You.</font/></center></div>";
header("Refresh:5; url=myfbmainpage.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

header("Refresh: 5;");
header("Location: myfbmainpage.php");